# Firebase Phone Authentication SMS limit

Tags: android, firebase

I have implemented Phone Authentication in my application, and it had been working fine until last night, when suddenly no codes by SMS were received anymore. The authentication process proceeded smoothly, but no SMS.
When I tried using another phone number from my app in my phone, an SMS was received, but of course the authentication wasn't complete, since it wasn't my phone that received it.

I read in the official docs about the limits on SMS sent, but that was 500/IP/hour, which the frequency of my testing (I tested 34 times in the period of around a day) comes no where near...

The problem is that I depend on `onCodeSent()` method which is invoked when an SMS with the code is sent to display a dialog, which when dismissed will complete the sign-in process. Without the SMS, `onCodeSent()` isn't invoked, therefore the dialog won't be displayed, and thus can't be dismissed, which in turn won't complete the sign-in process.
Can somebody help?

**P.S.**: If the question isn't in the right place, please tell me. I can be considered a fairly new member of Stack Overflow, so I don't know that much about the rules.

Comment: @Hime-sama I had same problems with you, that I need to know too. So, I vote. Ur question has so many texts, pls edit and briefly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was happening:

Basically, for some reason, the instant verification or auto retrieval of code in my phone (which for some reason wasn't working before) kicked in, perhaps because of the number of SMS sent to the same number.

After searching the net for some time, some misunderstandings I had about the process of phone number authentication of firebase got corrected:

- `onCodeSent()` is not invoked in cases of instant verification or auto-retrieval of code, the latter of which detects the incoming of the SMS to your phone.
- `onVerificationCompleted()` is **only** invoked in cases of instant verification or auto-retrieval of code.

In other words, both work separately from each other, and I had to take measures to finish the sign-in process in case no SMS was sent.

Hopefully this helps anyone with the same problem.